# Running portable Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, lenovo

I am trying to run Ubuntu 16.04 from a portable hard drive on different computers. I used Ubuntu from the external hard drive on a Lenovo Y40 laptop with an AMD radeon graphics card. On my Desktop with a NIVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 card, I can log in, but quickly the computer freezes and I cannot interact with Ubuntu at all.

At first I assumed it was an issue with the "on laptop close" settings putting Ubuntu into sleep mode. I turned off the "on laptop close" setting, but ran into the same problem. I looked around and people seem to point to a difference in the graphics drivers. On the laptop, Ubuntu shows that it is using the Intel Haswell Mobile. I am now unsure if the problem is in the graphics, the laptop settings, or am I attempting something impossible and wondering if there is a way to boot Ubuntu on any computer regardless of graphics.

Sorry for the lengthy question never asked on this forum before if i forgot to mention something please tell me.

Comment: 1) add the graphics drivers for the Intel card to the installation. 2) the resolution for the desktop needs to be one that is supported by both computers. since you lockup after login, this is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around a little and was able to find the issue. The issue was actually that on my desktop, I forgot I spit the monitors across graphics cards. One I unplugged the monitor connected to the motherboard not the Nvidia, the issue was resolved.